# How can I stop the onCreate()

Tags: android, oncreate

I have a flash light app class as follows;

```
public class SimpleNotificationAppActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
Camera cam = null;
ImageButton ib1;
Parameters para;
PowerManager pm;
WakeLock wl;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "whatever");
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

wl.acquire();
initialize();
ib1.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private void initialize() {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 ib1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ib2);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 if (cam == null) {
cam = Camera.open();
para = cam.getParameters();
para.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
cam.setParameters(para);
 } else {
para.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
cam.setParameters(para);
cam.release();
cam = null;

}
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onPause();
wl.release();
finish();
}
}
```

This class runs perfectly however if I go to the home screen, or turn off the screen, while the app is still running, when I go back to the app it sets the cam = null again, meanwhile cam was set to android.hardware.camera here is the log cat;

```
01-31 06:36:52.896: I/NotificationReceiverActivity(31188): CREATING NOWnull
01-31 06:36:52.956: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(31188): <ConfigWindowMatch:2087>: Format RGBA_8888.
01-31 06:36:54.408: I/NotificationReceiverActivity(31188): AAandroid.hardware.Camera@41cc75d0
01-31 06:36:58.912: I/NotificationReceiverActivity(31188): CREATING NOWnull
01-31 06:36:58.952: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(31188): <ConfigWindowMatch:2087>: Format RGBA_8888.
01-31 06:37:01.365: D/AndroidRuntime(31188): Shutting down VM
01-31 06:37:01.365: W/dalvikvm(31188): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x411d6360)
01-31 06:37:01.365: E/AndroidRuntime(31188): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-31 06:37:01.365: E/AndroidRuntime(31188): java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
01-31 06:37:01.365: E/AndroidRuntime(31188):    at android.hardware.Camera.native_setup(Native Method)
01-31 06:37:01.365: E/AndroidRuntime(31188):    at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:371)
01-31 06:37:01.365: E/AndroidRuntime(31188):    at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:344)
01-31 06:37:01.365: E/AndroidRuntime(31188):    at de.vogella.android.notificationmanager.NotificationReceiverActivity.onClick(NotificationReceiverActivity.java:50)
01-31 06:37:01.365: E/AndroidRuntime(31188):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4192)
01-31 06:37:01.365: E/AndroidRuntime(31188):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17254)
01-31 06:37:01.365: E/AndroidRuntime(31188):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
01-31 06:37:01.365: E/AndroidRuntime(31188):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-31 06:37:01.365: E/AndroidRuntime(31188):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-31 06:37:01.365: E/AndroidRuntime(31188):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
01-31 06:37:01.365: E/AndroidRuntime(31188):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-31 06:37:01.365: E/AndroidRuntime(31188):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-31 06:37:01.365: E/AndroidRuntime(31188):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
01-31 06:37:01.365: E/AndroidRuntime(31188):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
01-31 06:37:01.365: E/AndroidRuntime(31188):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You cannot "stop" onCreate().  It is a fundamental part of how Android works.  You should a) read, and learn, about the Activity life cycle b) do your initialisation in onResume() and disconnect the camera service in onPause() and c) fix the bug.  You cannot connect to the camera service, because you didn't release it.

Comment: As I mentioned in your last question, Reload the Camera in the onResume method instead of the onClick method.

Comment: The thing is, I want the camera to be on if I'm on the home screen or the screen is of, hence I don't wish to disconnect.

Comment: Then you need a background service.  It is not possible with an app.

Answer (score 2):

Read carefully all 10 points explained in the developer guide http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html

Especially the number 10:

To take pictures with this class, use the following steps:

1. Obtain an instance of Camera from open(int).
2. Get existing (default) settings with getParameters().
3. If necessary, modify the returned Camera.Parameters object and call
   setParameters(Camera.Parameters).
4. If desired, call setDisplayOrientation(int).
5. Important: Pass a fully initialized SurfaceHolder to
   setPreviewDisplay(SurfaceHolder). Without a surface, the camera will
   be unable to start the preview.
6. Important: Call startPreview() to start updating the preview
   surface. Preview must be started before you can take a picture.
7. When you want, call takePicture(Camera.ShutterCallback,
   Camera.PictureCallback, Camera.PictureCallback,
   Camera.PictureCallback) to capture a photo. Wait for the callbacks
   to provide the actual image data.
8. After taking a picture, preview display will have stopped. To take
   more photos, call startPreview() again first.
9. Call stopPreview() to stop updating the preview surface.
10. **Important: Call release() to release the camera for use by other
     applications. Applications should release the camera immediately in
     onPause() (and re-open() it in onResume()).**

You need to call `cam.release();` every time you finished using the camera.

Comment: I get what you are saying but, I want to be able to run the camera while I'm on the home screen, which this app does perfectly, it's just the problem that when I get back to the app, it sets the cam=null, while it is turned on and cam=android.camera.hardware..... I don't want to release it

Comment: By the way, I'm not taking pictures!! It's just a flashlight app

Answer (score 0):

Check your logic in `onClick`... you are setting `cam = null;` every time it is clicked and isn't already null.

Comment: if I don't set it to null, then I can't check if it's on or not, the problem is that, when I go to home screen or something, I find it has set itself to null once I open the project again, while the camera light is still on. But if I turn of the light, and surf and get back to the app, the app doesn't crash.